# Upgrade from SQL Server Express with Advanced Services to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-express

How do I upgrade my SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition?

Please do let me know.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: not really a programming question - recommending super user or one of the other admin stack sites

Comment: Yes i know but i thought i would just put it out here and see if some one has any idea how to do this?

Comment: dbs.stackexechange.com would be a better place

Answer (score 0):

click on the installer, and on one of the tabs, there is an edition upgrade option.